# What params is devise_auth_token expecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api

Devise_auth_token newbie here. I have a rails 5 api only app. I'm trying to make requests to my api using curl and I have managed to do so successfully except for when I want to sign in a user.

```
curl -XPOST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "session": { "email":"example2@gmail.com", "password": "password"}}' localhost:3000/auth/sign_in
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. As I said, for some reason there is no problem when creating a user. When trying to sign in I get this error

```
{"errors":["Invalid login credentials. Please try again."]}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your rails logfile?

Comment: @Eric Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-11-18 14:52:41 -0500
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"session"=>{"email"=>"example2@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameter: session
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: @Eric that was the logged result of the request I made.

Comment: Are you sure the json needs to be wrapped with `:session`?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/rjurado01/rails_jwt_auth

Answer (score 0):

```
    curl -v -XPOST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{  "email":"admin@example.com", "password": "password"}' localhost:3000/auth/sign_in
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
    > POST /auth/sign_in HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
    > Host: localhost:3000
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Type: application/json
    > Content-Length: 55
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 55 out of 55 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    < access-token: Bm3FaRpSAjT-EtTrj8Ucww
    < token-type: Bearer
    < client: 6XCiYTxcEITVRZItRKFa8w
    < expiry: 1480750998
    < uid: admin@example.com
    < ETag: W/"be9091473a08ccf2672b9685eb25caa2"
    < Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
    < X-Request-Id: 4996fb00-a45c-41e4-b30b-c86bc10b24d5
    < X-Runtime: 0.737506
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    <
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    {"data":{"id":1,"email":"admin@example.com","provider":"email","uid":"admin@example.com","name":null,"nickname":null,"image":null}}
```

Use -v for curl - it will give you many clues.
Comment was right - do not place login / password inside `session`.

Snip from [TL;DR](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#token-header-format) that you should read thoroughly:

> The authentication headers consists of the following params: `access-token`, `client`, `expire`, `uid`
>
> The authentication headers required for each request will be available in the response from the previous request.